# Jinja Vim plugin not working

Tags: vim, jinja2

I want to have my `.html.twig` files highlighted as Jinja files. (There doesn't seem to be a good Twig plugin for Vim out there, so I'm using Jinja instead.) I downloaded `jinja.vim` from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1856) and put the at `~/.vim/ftplugin/jinja.vim`. I also added these lines to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.twig set filetype=jinja
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.html.twig set filetype=jinja
```

However, when I open a `.html.twig` file, there's no syntax highlighting whatsoever. I haven't installed a Vim plugin before, so I'm guessing I missed some step. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't read the installation instructions given on the page you linked.

Comment: Yup, looks like I missed this crucial tidbit: "Copy the jinja.vim into your ~/.vim/syntax folder". Doing that made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the jinja.vim file in `~/.vim/syntax` instead of `~/.vim/ftplugin`. If there's still no syntax highlighting try typing `:syntax on`. If that works you need to add a line that says `syntax on` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Putting the file in `~/.vim/syntax` did the trick. Thanks. (I already had `syntax on`.)

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.twig set syntax=jinja
```

('syntax' instead 'filetype')

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
syntax on
```

to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: When I do that I get `E475: Invalid argument: syntax on`.

Comment: My bad. Put `syntax on` on its own line. Or simply type `:syntax on` with one of those files in the active window.

Answer (score 0):

I've also problems with Twig highlighting in VIM.

So I used this plugin: https://github.com/evidens/vim-twig

If you need Twig support for custom file extensions (like I do) add following lines to your .vimrc:

```
" highlight syntax in .tpl files as Twig
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tpl set filetype=html.twig
```

Sample outcome:
[image]